# android studio - Dart - Target URI Doesnt exist

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, dart

In Android Studio, for the dependency English_words

```
package:english_words/english_words.dart
```

**Target URI Doesnt exist**

Comment: did you add `english_words: [version constraint]` to `dependencies:` in `pubspec.yaml` and run `flutter packages get`?

Comment: Yes, I solved it by restarting the Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. By restarting Android studio after clicking on packages get